# Save current subst replacement for later use

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have the following code:

```
subst /d n:
subst n: C:\Temp
REM build
subst /d n:
subst n: @PreviousFolder
```

I want to know what is the previous folder assigned to drive N:, so I can restore it in the last line of code (here I use `@PreviousFolder`, but I don't know its value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
FOR /f "tokens=2*" %%f IN ('subst ^| find "N:\:"') DO set PREVIOUSFOLDER=%%g
```

Comment: and then use `SUBST N: %PreviousFolder%`